# How to check whether a given BST is valid or not?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to check whether a given binary tree is a Binary Search Tree or not. What I am trying to do is perform an inorder traversal of the binary tree and compare the current element with the previous element. In case the current element is greater we go on and check further else the given tree is invalid.

```
int prev=0;
public int isValidBST(TreeNode A) {
    if(A==null)
    return 1;
    isValidBST(A.left);
  //  System.out.println("val "+A.val);
   if(A.val<=prev)
   return 0;
   // else if(A!=null){
    prev=A.val;

    //System.out.println("prev "+prev);
    isValidBST(A.right);
    if(isValidBST(A.right)==1&&isValidBST(A.left)==1)
    return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

So this is the code that I have written. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using 0/1 instead of boolean?

Comment: calling isValidBST twice for left and right is bound to create havoc with your global variable.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a case where your code does not produce the correct output (in other words, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Answer (score 1):

Only one recursive call per subtree! Use boolean!

```
int prev=0;
public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode A) {
    if( A == null ) return true;
    if( ! isValidBST(A.left) ) return false;
    if( A.val <= prev ) return false;
    prev = A.val;
    if( ! isValidBST(A.right) ) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Sorin Thanks! I was just about to fix that :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Regarding the return type of the function, I was practicing on a website where the function signatures are already defined so I have to work with what is given.

Comment: Well, you can easily revert to int.

Answer (score 1):

1. suggestion: You can make your method return boolean instead of int.
2. Also, I prefer to take a null node instead of an variable. This way you can make your tree storing -ve values and other than integers too(just need to change comparison logic).
3. If you want your tree to have non-distinct values too, then you can remove the equal sign from `node.data <= prev.data`

   ```
   TreeNode prev=null;
   public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode node)
   {
       //null is a valid bst
       if(node==null){
           return true;
       }

       // traverse the tree in inorder fashion and
       // keep a track of previous node
       if (!isValidBST(node.left)){
           return false;
         }

       // compare current data with previous one
      if (prev != null && node.data <= prev.data){
          return false;
      }

      prev = node;

      //check right subtree
      return isValidBST(node.right);
   }
   ```

Comment: First: *thaen you can remove the qual*, Second: https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html

Comment: Corrected the first one. Didn't get why you mentioned the second link as reference here.

Comment: Much better :-)